# how to delete tensorflow model before retraining

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can't retrain my image classifier with new images, I get the following error:

AssertionError: Export directory already exists. Please specify a different export directory: /tmp/saved_models/1/

How do I overwrite this or delete it? I can't seem to find it's location on the disk.

Comment: Are you looking for the directory from your root directory (`/tmp/...`) rather than home (`~/tmp/...`)?

Comment: Can you expand on your question by posting the code you use to save and load your model? There's more than one way you might be saving and loading a model in tensorflow.

Answer (score -1):

just delete c:\tmp or d:\tmp Dir. Depends on where python is installed.

Comment: Do you mean delete the *contents* of these directories, or the directories themselves?