# Tensorflow object detection API using cnn

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Tensorflow object detection API using cnn**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "export_inference_graph.py", line 147, in tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\Ali Salar\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "export_inference_graph.py", line 143, in main
FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape)
File "C:\tensorflow2\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 453, in export_inference_graph
graph_hook_fn=None)
File "C:\tensorflow2\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 421, in _export_inference_graph
placeholder_tensor, outputs)
File "C:\tensorflow2\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 280, in write_saved_model
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_path)
File "C:\Users\Ali Salar\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\sit`enter code here`e-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py", line 90, in init
"directory: %s" % export_dir)
AssertionError: Export directory already exists. Please specify a different export directory: inference_graph\saved_model
```

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682236/how-to-delete-tensorflow-model-before-retraining

Answer (score 0):

It's saying the directory already exists. Either change your command in the terminal to point to a new directory or remove everything in this directory that you are currently setting as the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 export_inference_graph.py \
--input_type image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path YOUR_PIPELINE.CONFIG_FILE_PATH \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix YOUR_MODEL_CHECKPOINT_PATH  \
--output_directory exported_graphs/saved_model2
```

Your try changing output directory.For example exported_graphs/**saved_model2** as above.